# forms in Django does not register the data in the database

Tags: python, django

I'm stuck I try a lot of things to make it work, but always the same problem the form dose note save the data at all

and the any error that I get is the message error (what I writ in the message)

all i get is a change in the url like this

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/appointement/create_appointement_2?patient=patient+12&initial-patient=patient+12&doctor=2&date=2021-04-02&start_time=16%3A30`

is there anything that can show me the error or if anyone have this problem be for a few hits will be awesome?

this is my models .py

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    user_ho_add = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_ho_add_appointment')
    patient = models.CharField(null=True,max_length = 200, default=defaultTitle)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='doctor_app')
    date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, default=timezone.now) 
    start_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=timezone.now)
    end_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=timezone.now)
```

and this is my forms.py

```
class AppointmentForm_2(forms.ModelForm):
    doctor = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(type_of_user=TypeOfUser.DOCTOR))
    # patient = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.filter(type_of_user=TypeOfUser.PATIENT))
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}), input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
    start_time = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'time'}), input_formats=settings.TIME_INPUT_FORMATS)
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ('patient', 'doctor', 'date', 'start_time')
```

and this is the views.py

```
@login_required
def create_appointement_2(request):
    user = get_user_model()
    patients = User.objects.filter(type_of_user=TypeOfUser.PATIENT)
    form_appointment_2 = AppointmentForm_2(request.POST or None)
    if request.user.is_doctor() or request.user.is_reception():
        if request.method=='POST':
            form_appointment_2 = AppointmentForm_2(request.POST or None)
            user = get_user_model()
                
            if form_appointment_2.is_valid():
                form_appointment_2.save(commit=False)
                
                form_appointment_2.user_ho_add = request.user
                # form_appointment.end_time = form_appointment.start_time + timedelta(minutes=30)
                start_time = form_appointment_2.start_time 
                future_time = dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, start_time.hour, start_time.minute, start_time.second, start_time.microsecond) + timedelta(minutes=30)
                form_appointment_2.end_time = dt.time(future_time.hour, future_time.minute, future_time.second, future_time.microsecond)
                form_appointment_2.save()
                messages.success(request, 'appointment added')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Error')
        else:
            return render(request, 'appointement/add_appointement2.html', {'user_form':form_appointment_2,'patients':patients })
    
        return render(request, 'appointement/add_appointement2.html', {'user_form':form_appointment_2,'patients':patients })
```

and this the html file

```
<body>
    {% if form.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible col-12 mx-1" role="alert">
        <div id="form_errors">
            {% for key, value in form.errors.items %}
            <span class="fieldWrapper">
                    {{ key }}:{{ value }}
                </span> {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            {{ user_form.media }} {{ user_form }} {% csrf_token %}

            <button type="submit" value="create_appointment">
                ok
            </button>
        </form>

    </div>

</body>
```

I try to add the error tag, but it shows nothing, all i get is a change in the url like this

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/appointement/create_appointement_2?patient=patient+12&initial-patient=patient+12&doctor=2&date=2021-04-02&start_time=16%3A30`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are getting the data in the url that means you need to add **method="POST"** to your form tag in the html file